# statmodels STL not capturing seasonalities

Tags: fft, statsmodels

I am trying to use statmodels STL decomposition function to find the seasonalities in my time-series. I have for simplicity superpositioned two sine series, and am trying to get the STL to find both my seasonalities. I am struggling to make it do that, and I do not fully understand the input-parameters to the function.

Is it not so that STL can find "all" the seasonalities in your time series? Or will you have to specify your expected periods for it to decompose?

Below is an example with period 31 and 7 sine series and a  STL(df,period=37):

[image]

Comment: Why is period 37 when you know the period is 31? STL doesn't find anything.  It applies a specific decomposition based on LOWESS given the parameters provided. It also only can decompose a single seasonal component.

Comment: I just set this parameter as i iterated through value and this showed to give good results. But thank you very much for getting back to me! I conclude with that STL is not the right tool for "auto-detection" of seasonalities. I would higly appreciate suggestions if there are other tools that do this.

Comment: You could fit ARIMA models with seasonal components and vary the seasonal period.  In principle this could work.  There are probably better ways though.